# Clipping support in XeTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex

In pdflatex I'm used to clip graphics using something like this:

```
\includegraphics[trim=14mm 0mm 14mm 0mm,clip,width=1.2cm]{image.jpg}
```

When I attempt this in XeLaTeX, no clipping occurs and I get a warning:

> Package xetex.def Warning: No clipping support in XeTeX yet

It is obvious, that I could clip the image with a separate tool outside TeX, but for several reasons I would like to do this automatically from inside TeX (e.g. when migrating large old documents to XeTeX without messing around with the files)

Two questions:

1. Is there any workaround I should be aware of to do the clipping automatically during the TeX run? E.g. by replacing `\includegraphics` by something else (TikZ?)
2. Does anyone know if someone is working on clipping from inside XeTeX? Maybe there is a beta I could try?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `graphics/x` output driver for XeLaTeX doesn't include clipping support yet. However, it is possible to clip using PGF/TikZ which brings his own driver (i.e. low level code) to do clipping.
I have brought this issue up on `comp.text.tex`: [Clipping support with XeLaTeX?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.text.tex/se8qapxOdew/discussion). Also in the meantime Joseph Wright and I produced a clipping driver for XeTeX: [Patch to add clipping support to XeTeX](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/pOR3Zv39TUA/02hiqt8TP94J).

In the meantime the simplest way to get clipping is to use my `adjustbox` package which uses its own driver internally, including for XeLaTeX.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% ...

\adjustbox{trim=14mm 0mm 14mm 0mm,clip,width=1.2cm}{\includegraphics{image.jpg}}

% or with newer versions of adjustbox:
\adjincludegraphics[trim=14mm 0mm 14mm 0mm,clip,width=1.2cm]{image.jpg}
% or
\adjustimage{trim=14mm 0mm 14mm 0mm,clip,width=1.2cm}{image.jpg}
```

Comment: `xetex.def` has some restrictions. The maintainers (Ross Moore and Jonathan Kew) seems not very familar with `\special`s of `xdvipdfmx`. I'm quite sure that `xdvipdfmx` can support clipping, since `dvipdfmx` (by Jin-Hwan Cho) supports clipping.

Comment: magic, exactly what I needed :-)

Comment: @Leo: yeah, as I said here and on c.t.t: the driver should be really be updated with code like the one used for PGF.

Comment: @Martin: Well, the `pgf`'s system layer for XeTeX also has [some restrictions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14148/package-pgf-warning-your-graphic-driver-pgfsys-xetex-def-does-not-support-patter). Pity.

Comment: @Leo: Yes, indeed. I was also thinking about mentioning it here. There is also an issue with XeLaTeX + preview + some TikZ stuff.

Comment: has the patch found its way in to XeTeX? Seems so, but is it correct. Please try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 5cm}, clip, width=\textwidth]{example-image}
 \end{figure} 
\end{document}` with Xe- and with PDFLaTeX. I am getting different results.

Comment: Does this question of mine illustrate a problem with adjustbox clipping? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315264/why-does-the-picture-appear-in-a-different-position-in-xelatex