# Trim, crop, clip not working as expected in XeTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, crop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clipping support in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/clipping-support-in-xetex)

Why does the crop feature not work in this example?
Secondary question: Is there a good and thorough example somewhere floating around the internet explaining how to work with the bounding box and viewport etc.?

As you can see when you look at it with draft enabled and then remove the `, draft` code, the image is actually not being cropped. Just moved upwards by the trim feature.

What I'm trying to achieve is to crop off the very first line of characters.

MWE to be run in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, 9pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% the ratio of the embedded PDF to the text on the page
\newlength\ratiowidth
\setlength\ratiowidth{.61\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\ratiowidth}
  \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\ratiowidth, page=1, trim=0 0 0 100, clip=true, draft]{GenesisTest.png}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: XeTeX does not have native clipping support. Martin Scharrer and I have recently done some work on fixing this at the driver level, but I am not sure if this has made it into the `graphics` driver at the moment.

Comment: @JosephWright: Ok, thanks. Any particular alternative suggestions to use at this point? I unfortunately need to use XelaTeX due to other requirements.

Comment: You can use my `adjustbox` package as an alternative. It includes a XeTeX clipping driver by itself. That's basically the same code @Joseph mentioned above.

Comment: I closed this now as duplicate of the earlier basically identical question because of house keeping reasons. I didn't remembered my earlier answer to that question before answering here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is currently no clipping support in XeTeX. A usuable driver was suggested by Joseph Wright and me a little while ago, but it will take a good while until it is in stable release. See [Clipping support in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/clipping-support-in-xetex/24954#24954) (which I just found after my initial answer, it is actually a general duplicate).

However, you can use my `adjustbox` package which is inspired by `graphicx` but allows to apply the modification keys like clipping to arbitrary content. The current version has now also special macros to apply them directly to images. This is particular useful because then the `adjustbox` clipping driver for XeTeX is used, which is part of the package.

You can simply load the `adjustbox` package instead or in addition to `graphicx` and then replace `\includegraphics` with `\adjincludegraphics` (which is short for `\adjustbox{<key=value options>}{\includegraphics{<filename>}`). There is also a `\adjustimage` macro which takes the key=value options as a mandatory argument instead of an optional one.

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, 9pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% the ratio of the embedded PDF to the text on the page
\newlength\ratiowidth
\setlength\ratiowidth{.61\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\ratiowidth}
  \begin{center}
\adjincludegraphics[width=\ratiowidth, page=1, trim=0 0 0 100, clip=true]{GenesisTest.png}
\end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Note that `trim` (with or without `clip`) is always applied to the original image, then the result is scaled to the given `width`! If you want to change the order, i.e. first resize than clip, you need to use `adjustbox`es `Clip=0 0 0 100` key instead. This one can actually be used multiple times. See the package manual for all details.

---

About the bounding box and viewport: You don't need to use the bounding box keys any longer if you use EPS, PNG or JPG images. They were only needed in older times when the bounding box couldn't be read from the files directly.
The `viewport` key is similar to `trim` but states the lower left and upper right corner relative to the reference point, which is the lower left corner. Instead, `trim` states the amount taken away from the left, bottom, right and top edges.

I made some diagrams for the new version of my `adjustbox` *bundle* (I'm planning to put the trim and clip box macros into a sub-package). See [the unfinished `trimclip` package manual](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/downloads/trimclip.pdf) starting from page 7.

Comment: Has clipping support made it into a stable release yet?

Comment: @Aaron: AFAIK yes.