# Why does the picture appear in a different position in XeLaTeX?

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdftex

Min reprex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to illustrate

\begin{document}
\adjustbox{trim={.5\width} 0 0 0,clip}{\includegraphics{example-image}}%

\end{document}
```

The `clip` is essential to reproduce.

Potential clue:

I am trying to display a two-page picture. I am using the [function from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right).

When I use `pdflatex` the picture displays as I intend it to, immediately under the caption.

[image]
[image]

When I use `XeLaTeX`, however, it displays half-way down the page (for `gull.jpg` or is completely absent for `example-image`).

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{afterpage,adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twopagepicture}[4]{%
    {\afterpage{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
            \caption{#4}%
        \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
            \let\mywidth\linewidth
        \adjustbox{trim=0 0 {.5\width} 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\mywidth]{#3}}}%
            \caption*{.}%
    \end{figure}%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
            \caption*{\phantom{#4}}%
        \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
            \let\mywidth\linewidth
        \adjustbox{trim={.5\width} 0 0 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\mywidth]{#3}}}%
    \end{figure}%
    }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
.
\twopagepicture{t}{l}{example-image}{Top caption}

\clearpage\clearpage
\includegraphics{example-image}

\end{document}
```

`\listfiles`

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/05/09 v1.0r Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2016/04/06 v4.08 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-
ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-xetex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for xetex
ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
showframe.sty    2011/02/24 v0.1i showframe (new impl., RN)
 eso-pic.sty    2015/07/21 v2.0g eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 At begin shipout hook (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
example-image.pdf    Graphic file (type QTm)
```

Comment: looks odd, it would be good if you could simplify this to an example using `example-image` (a test file already in tex distributions) and without all the after page and float tests

Comment: I've taken your comment on board. Interestingly, `example-image` doesn't appear on the page when compiled using `xelatex`. (In the `gull` and my particular example the image occurs about half-way down the page.)

Comment: Do you have two different versions of your image (for example, `gull.jpg` and `gull.eps`)? If so, it may be that XeLaTeX is picking up a different file, which might have a different bounding box.

Comment: Hi, which version of XeLaTeX and adjustbox are you using?

Comment: Latest `xetex` and `adjustbox` `2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)`

Comment: Somewhat perverse to be closed as a duplicate of a question asked afterwards. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same bug reported here: [\clipbox of a \scalebox not working properly in xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331780/clipbox-of-a-scalebox-not-working-properly-in-xelatex).

Joseph provided a fix:

```
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\@cliptoboxdim#1{%
    \setbox #1=\hbox{%
      \Gin@defaultbp\WIDTH{\wd #1}%
      \Gin@defaultbp \DEPTH {\dp #1}%
      \@tempdima \ht #1%
      \advance\@tempdima\dp#1%
      \Gin@defaultbp \TOTALHEIGHT {\@tempdima }%
      \special{pdf:literal q}% 
      \special{pdf:literal 0 -\DEPTH \space \WIDTH \space \TOTALHEIGHT \space re W n }%
      \rlap{\copy #1}%
      \special {pdf:literal Q}%
      \hskip\wd#1%
    }%
  }
\fi
\makeatother
```

Applying Joseph's fix to your code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{afterpage,adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twopagepicture}[4]{%
    {\afterpage{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
            \caption{#4}%
        \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
            \let\mywidth\linewidth
        \adjustbox{trim=0 0 {.5\width} 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\mywidth]{#3}}}%
            \caption*{.}%
    \end{figure}%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
            \caption*{\phantom{#4}}%
        \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
            \let\mywidth\linewidth
        \adjustbox{trim={.5\width} 0 0 0,clip}{\includegraphics[width=2\mywidth]{#3}}}%
    \end{figure}%
    }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\@cliptoboxdim#1{%
    \setbox #1=\hbox{%
      \Gin@defaultbp\WIDTH{\wd #1}%
      \Gin@defaultbp \DEPTH {\dp #1}%
      \@tempdima \ht #1%
      \advance\@tempdima\dp#1%
      \Gin@defaultbp \TOTALHEIGHT {\@tempdima }%
      \special{pdf:literal q}% 
      \special{pdf:literal 0 -\DEPTH \space \WIDTH \space \TOTALHEIGHT \space re W n }%
      \rlap{\copy #1}%
      \special {pdf:literal Q}%
      \hskip\wd#1%
    }%
  }
\fi
\makeatother
.
\twopagepicture{t}{l}{example-image}{Top caption}

\clearpage\clearpage
\includegraphics{example-image}

\end{document}
```

**XeLaTeX:**

[image]

**PDFLaTeX**

[image]

The problem resides in `trimclip`, which has some outdated code.