# Compatibility between Tikzlibrary with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, tikzlibrary

I have a problem using `tikzlibrary` in `XeLaTeX`. I have compiled a sample code in `pdfLaTeX`, and it works. But I can't change my whole document to `pdfLaTeX`, because I would have problems with fonts:

[image: 3]

So, I consider the main problem is the compatibility of `tikzlibrary` with `XeLaTeX`; it happens with all patterns. I attached two different pictures to depict the problem.

P.D. I'm using Texpad software, and TexLive2013.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [pattern=vertical lines] (67mm,20mm)rectangle(150mm,30mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With `XeLaTeX`:

[image: 1]

With `pdfLaTeX`:

[image: 2]

Also there is a warning in the log file of my document:

> Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-xetex.def does not
>   support patterns. This warning is given only once on input line 1744.

### Update

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14148/package-pgf-warning-your-graphic-driver-pgfsys-xetex-def-does-not-support-patte) I've found the problem. Any different suggestions to deal with?

This is the list of the packages versions:

```
 *File List*
Desarrollo.tex
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package
 spanish.ldf
subcaption.sty    2013/02/03 v1.1-62 Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)
background.sty    2012/08/06 v2.0 background material
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
everypage.sty    2007/06/20 1.1 Hooks to run on every page
afterpage.sty    1995/10/27 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
floatrow.sty    2008/08/02 v0.3b floatrow: float package extension
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
      bm.sty    2004/02/26 v1.1c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
dateiliste.sty    2012/10/13 v0.6 Ausgabe der Dateiliste (PE)
 rcsinfo.sty    2005/02/20 v1.10
 rcsinfo.cfg
ltxtable.sty    1995/12/11 v0.2 longtable/tabularx merge (DPC)
tabularx.sty    1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
longtable.sty    2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
csquotes.sty    2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
csquotes.def    2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2013/05/01 v2.6 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/05/01 v2.6 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  blx-dm.def
 numeric.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/05/01 v2.6 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/05/01 v2.6 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2013/05/01 v2.6 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2013/05/01 v2.6 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
pgfplots.sty    2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
multirow.sty    
threeparttable.sty    2003/06/13  v 3.0
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
l3basics.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
  xparse.sty    2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many other characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
easylist.sty    2010/02/28 v.1.3 Numbered items with a single command.
  layout.sty    2000/09/25 v1.2c Show layout parameters
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
  hhline.sty    1994/05/23 v2.03 Table rule package (DPC)
fancyhdr.sty    
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
 spanish.lbx    2013/05/01 v2.6 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
ltcaption.sty    2013/02/03 v1.3-62 longtable captions (AR)
fr-longtable.sty    2007/11/28 v0.1b (beta) floatrow: additions for longtable
Desarrollo.bbl
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
Desarrollo.out
Desarrollo.out
se-ascii-print.def    2011/12/02 v1.10 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
    dimp.png    Graphic file (type QTm)
    emp1.png    Graphic file (type QTm)
    emp2.png    Graphic file (type QTm)
Desarrollo.filelist    2014/05/26 --- automatically generated filelist
 eu1lmtt.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
```

Comment: The above compiles with `pfdlatex` and `XeLaTeX` for me.

Comment: works without error here, what error do you get, copy the exact error from the log file and paste it in to your question

Comment: @PeterGrill I just edit the question, and I added pictures.

Comment: @Isai: I get the same results for both cases (your `pfdLaTeX` image) with a recently updated TeXLive2013. Can you add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}` and post the versions of the packages you have.

Comment: @PeterGrill Which package is the most important for?: `tikz.sty` v2.10-2010; `xetex.def`v0.96-2013

Comment: Given that various of us (including myself) can compile the document with no problems, it's likely that one or more of your package is outdated.  So you need follow Peter's suggestion to add `\listfiles` to your document preamble and add the log output that shows the versions and dates of all the packages loaded so that we can compare to find the offending problem. It's possible that your TikZ is out of date, but that's a large number of individual files, not just a single package, so without knowing the full list, there's no sure way to tell.

Comment: @AlanMunn I found this warning: `Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-xetex.def does not support patterns. This warning is given only once on input line 16.` I linked a question about the same problem.

Comment: @Isai *Please* respond to Peter's and my comment, and there is likely a solution to your problem.  Does TeXpad allow you to update packages or have locally installed packages?  If you can update it, then do so, since the rest of us have no problems compiling your file correctly; if you can't update but can install local packages, the list you provide using `\listfiles` will allow us to tell you which particular packages might need to be updated.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have a TeX Live Utility to update, but updates are blocked until a new release according to a message when running. I update my question with versions of the packages.

Comment: @Isai The list you have posted is not the list generated by compiling your sample document. And also, it has been generated with `pdflatex` and not `xelatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I considered that it would be more important the list of my document. Furthermore, you're right, I edited my question, and it has already generated with `xelatex`.

Comment: Your TeXLive2013 installation is not up to date: your version of TikZ/PGF is 2.10. The latest version provided by TeXLive 2013 is 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that patterns is not supported yet in `xelatex`: [Thread 1](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2011-May/020513.html),
[Thread 2](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2011-May/020515.html)

In manual, it can be read in page 109, about restrictions.

So, the unique solution is what in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14148/package-pgf-warning-your-graphic-driver-pgfsys-xetex-def-does-not-support-patte) is suggested.

Comment: That is an ancient thread, your example works in current xetex.